# Does Nikon or anybody else have an equivalent on the Canon MP-E 65?

Tags: lens, macro, canon-mp-e-65mm

The Canon MP-E 65 can do macro shots up to 5:1.  I've not been able to find anything like this for my Nikon system and you can't mount a Canon on a Nikon at all.  Do Nikon or any third party make a lens that goes above 1:1 like the MP-E and will mount to a Nikon?

Comment: Have you considered a bellows? You can go considerably bigger than 5:1 using a reversed wide-angle lens or a micro optic (like the old 12mm and 25mm Minolta bellows micros or Leitz micro optics). Life gets pretty manual at that level, but magnification isn't a worry. And some bellows allow for tilt and shift, which can help a lot.

Comment: @Stan Ya.  I've looked at a bellows and such before.  I have a few setups that get me past 1:1 - the lens is more about convenience.  I didn't think about TS though, that'd be handy.

Comment: I always thought that this lens was one of the "hat tricks" that the Canon lens lineup had in its pocket. No other mfg has the lens, and to get it you need to use the Canon system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good question, but the answer is **NO**, not just for Nikon but for any system that is not Canon.

As per the comments you got, there are ways to get that magnification but the lens is much more convenient. I have used one and it is quite awesome.